# ASP.NET SelectedValue which is invalid because it does not exist in the list of items. Parameter name: value

Tags: asp.net

I got error for DropDownList11 that say "'DropDownList11' has a SelectedValue which is invalid because it does not exist in the list of items.
Parameter name: value". The other dropdownlists with SQLDatasource work fine. I manually create this dropdownlist in edit DetailsView. Once it selected and click update, it will send it to SQL Server. Please help! Here a Code,

```
<EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList11" runat="server" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("Version") %>'>
                        <asp:ListItem Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Oracle 11g</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Oracle 11g R2</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Server 2008</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Server 2008 R2</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Server 2012</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>SQL Svr 2008 R2 SS%S</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>SQL Svr 2012 SS%S</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </EditItemTemplate>
```

Comment: what is Version, what do you think?

Comment: this is in <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Version" SortExpression="Version">. The Version is a column name in database table.

Comment: the problem is that DropDownList  doesn't have DataSource, and Bind doesn't know where is Version

Comment: ok how can I fix that without using DataSource?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No value that is already in dropdown (Oracle 11g, Oracle 11g R2,...) can be matched with value that you are binding (SelectedValue='<%# Bind("Version") %>').

Remove binding from dropdown and add asp label. Bind value to it and you will see what value are you trying to bind. Here is sample code for label:

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="<%# Eval("Version").ToString() %>"></asp:Label>
```

Comment: so just remove the SelectedValue='<%# Bind("Version") %>'. It seem work fine and after I click update, it stored in SQL Server. Does that correct way?

Comment: Yes remove this binding just temporary and add label to see what value you are trying to bind. Then you will need to figure out why this value is not present in dropdown. I assume you will need to add additional values (versions) to dropdown list.

Answer (score 0):

My Guess is that you are binding:

```
<%# Bind("Version") %>
```

And the value of Version is not in the list you have created. I would suggest taking that out of your code and seeing if it works. if it does then you know that you need to check that value and ensure it is in the list before you try and select it.

Comment: I have look at editTemplate in DetailsView and I do see a list of value I made on that dropdownlist11. I don't understand why value is not there even I see it there?

Comment: Well the value stored in your 'Version' field may not be in that list though. Try printing that value somewhere else. try what @Gregor Primar said to try. it is where I would go next.

Answer (score 0):

Like the error says, the value of "Version" from the db is probably not in the predefined list of values you have specified.  Try temporarily removing the dropdown list and just do:

```
<asp:TemplateField>
   <ItemTemplate><%#Eval("Version")%></ItemTemplate> 
</asp:TemplateField>
```

so you can see what the value of Version is to ensure you have it in your dropdown list.